# AIX Convert yyyymmdd to mmm dd

Tags: date, aix

I am looking for a way on AIX to convert "yyyymmdd" to "mmm dd" format - for example, `20150915` should become `sep 15`.

I am aware that this can be done with GNU date as `date --date="yyyymmdd"  +'%b %d'` but this isn't available in my environment.

How can I perform this conversion on AIX?

Edit : Thanks for the suggestions, I ended up with writing a script like below which worked

echo "Enter date in dd MON yy like \"12 SEP 15\" for 12th Sept 2015 "

read date month year

case $month in

"JAN") mm=01;;

"FEB") mm=02;;

"MAR") mm=03;;

"APR") mm=04;;

"MAY") mm=05;;

"JUN") mm=06;;

"JUL") mm=07;;

"AUG") mm=08;;

"SEP") mm=09;;

"OCT") mm=10;;

"NOV") mm=11;;

"DEC") mm=12;;

*)  echo "Please give proper parameter"

```
   exit ;;
```

esac

date_conversion=`echo "20"${year}${mm}$date`

Comment: I cannot think of standard util for it. Install a gnu date or use something else (C, Java, Perl, Python). What is best for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have GNU date you might want to make a script that does something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# convertDate.sh
date=$1
month=${date:4:2}
day=${date:6:2}
case $month in
   "01")
      echo "jan $day"
      ;;
   [...fill this in...]
   "09")
      echo "sep $day"
      ;;
esac
```

then you could call it like:

```
$ myDate=$(convertDate 20150915)
$ echo $myDate
sep 15
$
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install coreutils from AIX Toolbox which installs the GNU date command.

You can find it here: http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html

```
# /opt/freeware/bin/date --date="2016-07-20" +'%b %d'
Jul 20
```